# Notification-How to give alternate choice

Tags: android

can anybody tell me how to create a notification with toggle type icon.if i click the icon ,it has to toggle between ON/OFF.I seen some of the apps related to it.But if there is any code snippets,its highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Narayan

Answer (score 2):

You could just call some code to remove the current notification and recreate it with the toggled image on the event you get when a notification is selected.